# android gridview arabic letters displayed in opposed way

Tags: android, gridview

I am working in android app that contain two gridviews wiht arabic letters inside them, the problem is the arabic letters displayed in opposed way.

Comment: I think this is happening because you set rotationY in your gridView, which causes your gridview to be mirrored in relation to what you desire. What happens if you don't set it?

Comment: @Edson Menegatti  I will remove it and see the result.

Comment: @Edson Menegatti  it worked, it display the letters in the correct way but the problem is when I click at the letters to create the word the letters are added from left to right.

Comment: Then I'd suggest that you add the rotation Y to the top GridView and also to the views that are added to it. That way the grid will be populated right to left, but the view will be correctly oriented.

Comment: post the onclick for letters

Comment: @Samurai  I added the onclick code for the letters and word gridviews

Comment: @Edson Menegatti you mean like this: android:rotationY="180"  ?

Comment: Yes, but also add it to the children of gvLetters. So the layout that is inflated when rendering them also has this android:rotationY="180"